# launch activity with tab bar in Api 14?

Tags: android, tabs

I want to lunch an activity with tab bar. I've search in internet & I find some answer by `localactivitymanager` class & `getlocalactivitymanager()` method. But I use API 14 & in this API that class is depreciated.

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just depreciated, this is not a problem. You can still use it. 
I think it is depreciated because of fragments and fragmentManagers.